# struggling to understand bitwise operators in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am struggling to understandwhat the "if (i >> j) % 2 ==1 " does in the following function or any function for that matter?

```
def powerSet(items):

    N = len(items)
    for i in xrange(2**N): 
               combo = []
        for j in xrange(N):
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(items[j])
        yield combo
```

Comment: Better yet `if (i >> j) & 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It checks whether the `j`'th bit of the binary number `i`, counting from the end, is set. `i >> j` right-shift, so the final `j` bits are gone. `n % 2 == 1` is the familiar check for odd numbers, which in binary have their last bit set.

**EDIT**: this is generating a power set as follows. The outer loop walks through all `2**N` subsets of `items`, each represented as a binary integer. The inner loop then constructs the actual subset by checking which of the `N` final bits of these integers are set, using the bits as indicators of subset membership.

E.g., suppose that `N=5`. Then at some point, `i` will be `0b10011`. From that, the set `[items[0], items[1], items[4]]` can be constructed. First reverse the bits, because they're numbered right-to-left by `j`:

```
1          1         0          0          1
items[0]   items[1]  (nothing)  (nothing)  items[4]
```

(Try printing `i` and `combo` inside the inner loop.)

Comment: thanks I am getting closer to understanding :) what does the b represent in your binary 0b10011?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it's Python notation for a binary literal, just like `0x` starts a hex literal.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: forget about numbers for a minute. A binary integer is first and foremost a string of bits. Those can be interpreted as yes/no answers to the question, "does the subset include this item?"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I made a little table to clarify things, hope this helps.

Comment: that little table just completely explained all the parts I did not understand, thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can print the numbers in binary as the operation progresses to see how it works. Here's an example with i=1234 and j=4.

1234 in binary

```
>>> '{:b}'.format(1234)
'10011010010'
```

shifting right 4 places causes the rightmost bits (0010) to fall away

```
>>> '{:b}'.format(1234>>4)
'1001101'
```

the modulo operation divides by 2 and gives you the remainder

```
>>> '{:b}'.format((1234>>4)%2)
'1'
```

its also common to do this with the & operation

```
>>> '{:b}'.format((1234>>4)&1)
'1'
```

if you have a number where the 4th bit (from zero) is zero, you get a zero

```
>>> '{:b}'.format((1234+0b10000>>4)&1)
'0'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate flavour to larsmans already complete solution, here is how I understood it.

i >> j simply means i/pow(2,j), which mathematically means i/2^j [obviously we are in integer space]. lets set n=i/2^j. When you have n % 2 == 1 you ask if n mod 2 is 1? if it is then n must be odd, else n must be even.

Source: 
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html